# Request with retrofit2 using multi-networking API

Tags: android, networking, okhttp, retrofit2

I'm trying to make a request which needs to be done via Mobile connections if the user allows it. 
I'm current using retrofit2 with rxjava for the requests, although whenever the user has a Wi-Fi and Mobile connection the only way to choose which network mobile to make the request, without additional permissions to change the network, is like this:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkRequest.Builder req = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
            req.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
            cm.requestNetwork(req.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                   //do the request here
                }

            });
  }
```

Is there a way to use retrofit using the multi-network API or passing a NetworkRequest as presented above?

Or the only is to do the request manually using OkHttp or an URLConnection?